# Can you transfuse a damaged structure while it is being built?

Tags: starcraft-2

Question is in the title - can you transfuse a damaged structure - e.g., a spine crawler - after it has suffered damage but is still under the process of being built from a drone? And if you can, what is the precise effect? Speaking only about Zerg structures, obviously.

Question is from this video:

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well. I've created a [video answer](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SNL5jREPfH4) to your video question!

Spoiler: NO. You cannot transfuse a building, as the message "Cannot target units under construction" states. What it also means is that you cannot transfuse larva-eggs and (I've not tested it, but think that it's the same) morphing units.

Answer (score 1):

That's a negative: http://us.battle.net/sc2/en/forum/topic/3424682535

> Transfuse a building while it is being built is equivalent to terran being able to repair a building while it is being built.

People would be crying foul, saying that Terrans can't repair-build and Protoss can't Chronoboost-build.

As for repairing it if it's damaged while building, I don't think that's possible either (for the same reasons that Terran and Protoss can't).

One poster goes on to mention the balance issues that this caused in WarCraft III, with humans being able to speed build stuff.  Blizzard probably wanted to avoid this with SC2.

Comment: Well, correct me if I'm wrong, but in WC3 there wasn't a build timer. You just constructed a building and when it got to full HP it was done. With the independent build timer bar in SC2 this isn't a problem. It still might be a balance issue though: Zerg would be able to instantly wall off with full health spinecrawlers whereas pylons and supply depots can be killed early with a small concentrated blast.

Comment: Apologies; my bad. My intention was to ask about transfusing a **damaged** building under construction; it was obvious to me that you cannot use transfuse to speed up the building process itself. However re-reading my question it seems to have only been in my mind and not in the text :) question fixed.

Comment: Still don't think you can't do that either.  The thread I linked to is precisely about that, the poster asks: "I see no reason why the queen shouldn't be able to transfuse buildings *to try and save them* while they are building?"

Similarly in terms of balance, Terran and Protoss can't repair buildings as they are being damaged.  These days it's all about balance --- Blizzard can't do anything too unique for each race without whiners calling foul.

Best way to get the fastest and most concrete answer would be to just load up a custom map and give it a shot in a custom map with AI.

Comment: Regarding the first comment: You cannot wall off with spinecrawlers as good as with pylons or depots... speedlings for example still squeeze trough.